# What's the correct way to load Marionette (v3) with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, bower, marionette

I searched in vain all over Google on how to load **Marionette** *v3-pre.4* - latest version until now (July 2016) - with **RequireJS**.

The bundled version of the library seems to be broken for **RequireJS** so I have to manually include "*backbone.babysitter*" and "*backbone.radio*" which are required for this version of Marionette.

According to: **versioneye.com** I need:

- "*backbone.babysitter*" *1.0.0-pre.1* **and**
- "*backbone.radio*" * 2.0.0-pre.1*

So I tried installing them with **Bower**:

> bower install backbone.babysitter

It returned:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for backbone.babysitter, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) backbone.babysitter#^0.1.12 which resolved to 0.1.12
    2) backbone.babysitter#1.0.0-pre.1 which resolved to 1.0.0-pre.1 and is required by marionette#3.0.0-pre.4

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

I selected the 2nd one like this:

`? Answer !2`

It returned:

```
bower resolution    Saved backbone.babysitter#1.0.0-pre.1 as resolution
```

I did exactly the same with *backbone.radio*:

> bower install backbone.radio

Returned:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for backbone.radio, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) backbone.radio#^1.0.5 which resolved to 1.0.5
    2) backbone.radio#2.0.0-pre.1 which resolved to 2.0.0-pre.1 and is required by marionette#3.0.0-pre.4

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

Selected:

> ? Answer !2

Returned:

```
bower resolution    Saved backbone.radio#2.0.0-pre.1 as resolution
```

Everything seemed to be ok, but when I checked the version for these two libraries in each's "*bower.json*" file, I found out that:

*backbone.babysitter* is at:

```
  "name": "backbone.babysitter",
  "version": "0.1.11"
```

and *backbone.radio*:

```
  "name": "backbone.radio",
  "version": "1.0.4"
```

Where did I go wrong?

This is my *bower.json*:

```
{
  "name": "Example App",
  "authors": "Consta Gorgan",
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "~1.2.3",
    "backbone.radio": "~2.0.0",
    "backbone.babysitter": "~1.0.0",
    "marionette": "~3.0.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.15",
    "requirejs-plugins": "~1.0.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "backbone.radio": "2.0.0-pre.1",
    "backbone.babysitter": "1.0.0-pre.1"
  }
}
```

This is my shim file:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
    underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
    'backbone.radio': '../bower_components/backbone.radio/build/backbone.radio',
    'backbone.babysitter': '../bower_components/backbone.babysitter/src/build/backbone.babysitter',
    marionette: '../bower_components/marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: [
        'underscore',
        'jquery'
      ],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    marionette: {
      deps: [ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.radio', 'backbone.babysitter' ],
      exports: 'Marionette'
    }
  }
})
```

And this is how I load modules with RequireJS in my *app.js* file:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'marionette',
  'router'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette, Router) {
  'use strict'

  var init = function () {
    Router.init()
  }

  return {
    init: init
  }
})
```

Aaand this is the error I keep getting in my browser:

[image: Cannot set property 'VERSION' of undefined - *image*]

And this one after a few more seconds:

[image: Load timeout for modules: backbone.radio - *image*]

Comment: Have you tried [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)? Will make it a lot less painful.

Comment: Browserify is my favorite, but I have to use RequireJS due to some administrative reasons. Thanks for the tip tho !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `../bower_components/backbone.babysitter/src/build/backbone.babysitter` use `../bower_components/backbone.babysitter/lib/backbone.babysitter`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this, v3.0 changed to remove babysitter

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
        underscore: 'node_modules/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: 'node_modules/backbone/backbone',
        'backbone.radio': 'node_modules/backbone.radio/build/backbone.radio',
        marionette: 'node_modules/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'backbone.radio': {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'backbone'
            ],
            export: 'Radio'
        }
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        marionette: {
            deps: [ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.radio' ],
            exports: 'Marionette'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: One of the basic principles of using RequireJS: `shim` is only for non-AMD modules (code that does not call `define` to register as an AMD module). Every single shim you have there is superfluous. What RequireJS does with a `shim` set for an AMD module is *undefined*. It *may* have no effect, or it *may* lead to undesirable behavior.

Comment: Fair enough.  I don't actually use RequireJS, but was going off of the OP example.